# How to access local variable for closure in a jQuery custom plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is jQuery code to create a custom plugin.

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    get_me_now: 'abc',
    init : function( options ) { // how to access get_me_now in here? },
    show : function( ) { // IS   },
    hide : function( ) { // GOOD },
    update : function( content ) { // !!! }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }

  };

})( jQuery );
```

I have a variable 'get_me_now'. I call it like this: $('#test').tooltip('init');
How does the 'init' function get the 'get_me_now' variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
methods.get_me_now
```

You can just reference methods.